# Passing Phoenix.Token to and from browser

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m trying to use Openmaize for user authentication, and having trouble getting phoenix pass a token when a user logs in.  It appears that no token is assigned and passed to the client, and therefore Phoenix.Token.verify fails.

`IO.inspect(socket)` in `UserSocket.connect` returns this.

```
Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{}, channel: nil, channel_pid: nil,
     endpoint: SeatSaver.Endpoint, handler: SeatSaver.UserSocket, id: nil,
     joined: false, pubsub_server: SeatSaver.PubSub, ref: nil,
     serializer: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: nil,
     transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_name: :websocket,
     transport_pid: #PID<0.2098.0>}
```

I defined `set_current_user(user, conn)` function in authenticate.ex controller that looks like

```
  defp set_current_user(user, conn) do 
    token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", user.id)
    conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> assign(:user_token, token)
```

In the app.html.eex, the following has been added.

```
<script> window.userToken = “<%= assigns[:user_token] %>” </script>
<script src = “<%= static_path(@conn, “/js/app.js”) %>”></script>
```

in the `app.js`,

```
let socket = new Socket(”/socket”, {
   params: {token: window.userToken},
   …
})
```

and finally, user_socket.ex has

```
  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do

      case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user socket",
      token, max_age: @max_age) do
        {:ok, user_id} ->
          IO.inspect(user_id)
          {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, user_id)}
        {:error, _reason} ->
          :error     # this errors out because token is nil

      end
    end
```

Comment: Is window.userToken being set correctly? You can use `@user_token` in your template which will raise if it does not exist on assigns.

Comment: Thanks. It gives me an error. "assign @user_token not available in eex template"

Comment: Are you definitely calling set_user_token? Could you post the rest of the function?

Comment: As you suspected, it's not being called. I moved the code to router.ex and it is now working. I still don't know why the Openmaize. Authenticate plug didn't call the function.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add secret_key_base in config/config.exs.

`secret_key_base: xxxxx`